# How do I check whether a LTE network supports CAT M1?

Tags: communication, wireless, mobile-data, batteries

LTE CAT M1 is a low power communication channel for LTE networks designed for IoT use. How do I check whether a network supports it or not?

Carriers' help desk does not know anything about CAT M1. That is understandable because most users don't need to know about it. I may try other ways of getting this information from them but I guess if the network is up and running, one should simply be able look it up using appropriate hardware. As of now, I have a LTE phone (Nexus 5x) and the carrier's SIM.

Comment: You may need to talk to their business-to-business people, if they're building out support for this variation, there's quite likely someone in charge of selling it, and that's not the consumer helpdesk.

Comment: Yes, that option is always there. Looking for technical solution here.

Answer (score 5):

I tried hard to find out an AT command for that, but unfortunately I didn't find it.

Instead I found semi new slides about m1 and m2.

https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/SmallCellForum1/discussion-on-iot-technologies-cat-m1-and-nbiot-cat-m2

There it is mentioned that Verizon should soon / already have it nationwide, AT&T makes piloting in San Francisco and some other operators in other places, too.